Barbara Celarent
Below is a medieval mnemonic poem for the valid moods of the syllogism, which you can hear set to music by Renaissance composer Jacobus Handl-Gallus here (first verse only) and here (both verses but with finger-snapping).

Barbara, Celarent, Darii, Ferio.
Baralipton, Celantes, Dabitis, Fapesmo.
Frisesomorum.
Cesare, Camestres, Festino, Baroco.
Darapti, Felapton, Disamis, Datisi, Bocardo, Ferison.
Barbara, Celarent, Darii, Ferio.

Asserit A, negat E,
stant universaliter ambae.
Asserit I, negat O,
stant particulariter ambae.
Ecce tibi Sim armigeros ac: arma bono con:
servat maiorem variatque secunda minorem,
tertia maiorem variat servatque minorem.

A great answer would explain the whole mnemonic system,† but what has me puzzled right now is the last sentence. Who are the armigeros and what are the subject and verb relative to which the armigeros are in the accusative case? What does bono modify? What exactly is the metaphor with weapons? And what is Sim? I assume it's not "That I be"—or is it? I assume that the maior is the major term (the predicate of the conclusion) and the minor is the minor term (the subject of the conclusion), but what does it mean to conservare or variare them?
†The vowels are explained in the second verse.

@IlyaDaskevics That sounds like the basis of a good answer! While I'm delighted by the nonsense words that serve as mnemonics, I'm disappointed by nonsense grammar. But that would indeed explain the strangeness of the last sentence.
